# How to draw an elliptical arc?

Tags: r, image-processing, geometry, geospatial

I am trying to draw an arc-shape around a crescent inside an image and mask out everything around it. I used the function `draw.arc` from the `plotrix` package:

```
 plot(1:10, asp = 1,main="Test draw.arc")
 draw.arc(7,4,5, deg1=70, deg2=150, col="gold", lwd=70, lend=1)
```

I need to do similar arc but an elliptical one in order to use the x and y coordinates to do the mask

I have tried the following but it does not work:

```r
## Define parameters of the arc.
x = c(2,12)
y = c(5,10) 
c (center) = c(5,7)
## Define the angle theta
a = atan2(x[2]-c[2],x[1]-c[1])
b = atan2(y[2]-c[2],y[1]-c[1])
library(numbers)
b = modq(b-a)+a
theta<-seq(a,b,50)
d = (y-x)
r = d/2
x = c[1]+r*cos(theta)
y = c[2]+r*sin(theta)
## Define x and y using "Degrees" .
x = radius * 180 *cos(theta)/pi + x 
y = radius * 180 * sin(theta/pi) + y
plot(x, y, type='l')
```

Any hints or guidance to make it work?

Comment: Could you include a (manual) sketch of the expected output, including  the major and minor axis of the ellipse arc? The attempted code seems to relate to a parameterised circle rather than an ellipse.

Comment: @PeterI added a photo.

Comment: Great, could you include a sketch of the desired elliptical arc, including the major and minor axis.

Comment: @Peternot sure what you mean by the sketch. Reg the minor and major axis, I can say something 0.16 and 0.33, respectively.But those can be manipulated.

Comment: @Peter I guess the issue is related to how the starting and ending points are defined

Comment: The numbers you gave might be "semi-axes", which are the ellipse equivalent of the radius for a circle.  But you also need to define the directions of those axes, and the center of the ellipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand the question. Maybe you want something like this:

```r
library(PlaneGeometry)

# define an ellipse:
# centered at (0, 0)
# major radius 4
# minor radius 2
# angle 40 degrees
ell1 <- Ellipse$new(c(0, 0), 4, 2, 40)
# now define an arc on this ellipse
arc1 <- EllipticalArc$new(ell1, alpha1 = 25, alpha2 = 120)

# define another ellipse, "parallel" to the first one:
ell2 <- Ellipse$new(c(0, 0), 3, 1.5, 40)
# now define an arc on this ellipse
arc2 <- EllipticalArc$new(ell2, alpha1 = 25, alpha2 = 120)

# get the elliptical arcs as points:
n <- 100
path1 <- arc1$path(npoints = n)
path2 <- arc2$path(npoints = n)

# make the desired path
path2reversed <- path2[n:1, ]
path <- rbind(path1, path2reversed)

# plot
plot(NULL, xlim = c(-2, 1), ylim = c(0, 3), asp = 1, xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
polygon(path, col = "yellow")
```

[image]